# How to make a swift class conform to a protocol that requires a protocol-conform type for one of its properties?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a complex class hierarchy conform to protocols, which help me to reuse code fragments. To that end, I face the following issue: class A has a property b, that is an instance of class B. B does conform to `ProtocolB`. Now I want to define a protocol `ProtocolA`, such that A does conform to `ProtocolA` and that `ProtocolA` specifies b of type `ProtocolB`.

This is what I came up with:

```
class A {
    var b: B?
}

class B {}

protocol ProtocolA {
    var b: ProtocolB? { get }
}

protocol ProtocolB {}

extension B: ProtocolB {}
extension A: ProtocolA {}
```

Unfortunately, XCode shows the error:

> Type 'A' does not conform to protocol 'ProtocolA'.

It is important to mention, that I can not directly define classes A and B like:

```
class A: ProtocolA {
    var b: ProtocolB?
}

class B: ProtocolB {}
```

since the classes A and B are predefined by a library.

Comment: Do you need to use `ProtocolA` as the type of a variable or a method parameter? If so, you can't do this in a type-safe way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with associated types.

Declare an associated type in `ProtocolA`:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype BType: ProtocolB
    var b: BType? { get } // Note the change in the type of b
}
```

This is saying that `b` is an optional of some type that conforms to `ProtocolB`. What type exactly? That depends on the conformers of `ProtocolA`.

In `A`'s extension, you specify what `BType` is:

```
extension A: ProtocolA {
    typealias BType = B
}
```

And you're done!

As a result of this, you won't be able to use `ProtocolA` as the type of a variable:

```
var protocolA: ProtocolA? // error
```

Because you don't know what `b`'s type is.

Comment: Thank you a lot! One question regarding the use of `ProtocolA` as method parameter: Would this be correct:
`func foo<T: ProtocolA>(a: T) {}`

Comment: Yes you can use it as a type constraint, just not as a type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `associatedtype` for this:

```swift
class A {
    var b: B?
}

class B {}

protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype PB: ProtocolB
    var b: PB? { get }
}

protocol ProtocolB {}

extension B: ProtocolB {}
extension A: ProtocolA {}
```